# Word Quick Parts Field issue on Table of Contents page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

In MS Word 2010, I found [this guide](http://www.atoztoa.com/2010/02/adding-automatically-updating-chapter.html) on how to add the Heading 1 style to the footer of every page.

It was very helpful and did exactly what I needed except for one thing. When I set this up the page that hosts the table of contents the footer has the heading for my first chapter instead of "Table of Contents". I have a cover page as well so the "Different First Page" checkbox doesn't matter in this case.

I have looked in the Quick Links > Field and there is a TOC field, but this repeats on every page as well and that is not correct either.

[image: screenshot of issue]

**----UPDATE 2----**
[Link to .DOCX test file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qqm7p58622gwxut/Wo3dXnU7vz)

Any one have any idea on how to resolve this one?

Comment: Can you post an example screenshot or document for us to look at?

Comment: I added a screenshot. This is already out in the wild, but would still like to know how to resolve this. If I do a <RETURN> it goes away, if I do a <SHIFT> + <RETURN> it doesn't. The added space above "Overview" was worse than the footer being incorrect for us.

Comment: Wow that is a really strange situation, I can't do anything to reproduce that on my side. By any chance can you try extract just first few pages while still keeping the issue reproducible and attach the  document somewhere for us to download?

Comment: I think it probably has something to do with having a cover page as well as a TOC page. I'll see what I can do about extracting and putting up for DL somewhere.